# Nested for loop for SQL insertion of new value to all months, regions and departments at a time

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, winforms

I have 12 months,3 regions, 10 departments (fetching from database) and 100 customer names for all departments and 12 months. now I want to add new customer name to each department and 12 months, so I have written a nested for loop to insert data into the database.

```
for(int i=1; i<=12; i++)
{
    foreach(datarow dtregion in region.rows)
    {
        foreach(datarow dt in department.rows)
        {
            //SQL connection and insertion.
            //insert into tablename(customername) values...
            //newcust  where month=i and department=dt.field<0>
        }
    }
}
```

This takes more time looping each month, each region, 10 departments. Do we have any way to insert the new employee name to all months at a time or simplify this for loop?

Comment: Do not loop in client code - create according query and execute it.

Comment: SQL `insert into` allows you to insert multiple records at once. Doing so will be much faster than executing the inserts one by one.

Comment: If you still looking for exact answer to your problem, clear few things first. Are these different tables Months, Region,Department? Or you need to insert multiple rows in the same table with different values for department, month, region columns.

Comment: all values goes into same table.Let me explain, i have an employee named "Mark", i need to add his name to all 12 months at a time.need to excecute,                          insert into table values('Mark','asia','department1',;january')                                    this query 12 times for 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if you understand what I mean...
Instead of making multiple sql inserts, make a "script builder" and run it all at once.

```
//SQL connection...    
for(int i=1; i<=12; i++)
{
    foreach(datarow dtregion in region.rows)
    {
        foreach(datarow dt in department.rows)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("insert into tablename(customername) values...");
        }
    }
}
//EXECUTE sb.ToString()...
```